# why is this closing the new pop up window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a window and then redirecting the original page to a new location. It   opens the   window, however before redirecting the parent page, it closes the new   window too. How can I fix that

```
function orderPrint() {      
    var n = new Object();    
    n. ID = <?php echo $ID->ID; ?>;    
    n.action = posttothispage.php";    
    n.target = popWinCenterScreen("/common/html/empty.htm", parseInt(window.screen.height * 0.8), 796, "resize");    
    myFuction.PostRequest(n);    
    window.location = “someotherpagethanthis.php”;  
}
```

Comment: Is the code in real also syntactically invalid as in your question? A `"` is missing and there are curly quotes instead of straight quotes in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onbeforeunload method to trigger the redirect before the opened window closes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload